# Confused with this output in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *s="Peace";
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%s\n",s+1);
    printf("%s\n",s++);

}
```

Output:

```
Peace
eace
Peace
```

My query is while I did `s++` it should have print `"eace"` instead of `"Peace"`. Why is this happening?

Another question is `char *s="Peace";` this line stores the string literal in an anonymous array so when `s` points to `'P'` but when I only `printf("%d\n",s);` wrote this how could it able to print all the string? shouldn't it print only `"P"`?

Comment: Why do you think the `s++` line should have printed "eace"?

Comment: Did you really get "Peace" from "%d\n" ?

Comment: My bad I was testing the location while I get confused with the result I've changed it.

Comment: Add another `printf("%s\n",s);` after the last one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets decode it line by line:

```
char *s="Peace";
```

here `s` points to 'P'

```
printf("%s\n",s);
```

Prints entire string "Peace" as `s` is at 'P'. **That's what %s does actually**.

```
printf("%s\n",s+1);
```

Now `s` is at 'e' , so it will print "eace".

```
printf("%s\n",s++);
```

This would also print "eace" as you've used a post increment operator. If you had used `++s` instead then it would print "ace".

Answer (score 4):

`s++` is the *post*-increment operation. It returns the *current* value of `s` *then* increments `s`. To get what you want you need to use *pre*-increment, `++s`.

Comment: Umm as I'm not storing the result into any other variable isn't s++ and ++s meaning same? Just aksing I'm new in this field

Comment: No, they are not the same. Both of them do increment the value of `s`, but they differ in the value they return at the site where you call the operator. `++s` will return the incremented value. `s++` will return the original value and _then_ increment it. Another way to think about it is making functions for each one. `char* pre_increment(char* s) { s = s + 1; return s; }` and `char* post_increment(char* s) { char* orig = s; s = s + 1; return orig; }` (the real functions would use a char** parameter so that `s` is modified outside the scope of the functions, but that is the gist of it.

Answer (score 3):

Your evaluation of s++, the increment is after the valuation.  If you wish your increment to be before your use then you should be using ++s.  Changing this small bit will result in your desired output.

Try this:

```
char *s="Peace";
int counter;

for (counter=0;counter<=strlen(s);++counter)
{
    printf("%s\n",s+counter);
}
```